# Put all users into List after jda.retrieveUserById finished

Tags: java, multithreading, discord-jda

I'm designing a Discord bot via Java Discord API. I got a server point system which records point when a user speak in channel.
The server points are store in a `HashMap<String, Long> points`, which use the ID of user as key, and points as value. I want a command `/ranking` to show the ranking of points, here is my code:

```java
List<userAndBlocks> sorted = new ArrayList<>(points.size());
JDA jda = event.getJDA();
points.forEach((userID, blocks) ->
{
    User user = jda.getUserById(userID);
    if (user == null)
        jda.retrieveUserById(userID).queue(
                user1 -> sorted.add(new UserAndBlocks(user1, blocks)),
                throwable -> sorted.add(new UserAndBlocks(jda.getSelfUser(), 0L)));
    else
        sorted.add(new UserAndBlocks(user, blocks));
});
try
{
    Thread.sleep(1000L); //wait for retrieveUserById
}
catch (InterruptedException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.print('\u0007');
    FileHandle.log(e);
    System.exit(1);
}
sorted.sort((user1, user2) ->
{
    return Long.compare(user2.blocks, user1.blocks);
});
```

For `UserAndBlocks`, it is a record:

```java
public record UserAndBlocks(User user, long blocks) {}
```

I know that `getUserById` only get cached user, so I ask ChatGPT, and it told me to use `retrieveUserById`. As you can see, I traversed the whole map, use `retrieveUserById` to get users from their ID, and make the main thread sleep via `Thread.sleep(1000L)`, to buy some time for `retrieveUserById` method. But the list still didn't include every users that I'm sure in the map. How can I do that?

Comment: You could just block the thread by using #complete() instead of #queue()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDA is supposed to be used asynchronously using the callback strategy.
This means that you're supposed to not block any threads and await stuff but rather handle the things once they're done.

In your case, I see that you do multiple rest actions.
To do something once all of them are complete, use `RestAction.allOf()` to get one RestAction that is done once all the jobs finished.

Also, rather than doing the logic you have there with first getting it from cache and then checking if it's loaded is unnecessary, `retrieveUserById` will actually check the cache first and only load the user if they're not cached yet.